# Java & Multiline Batch Files

Tags: java, batch-file, if-statement, multiline, runtime.exec

I try to run batch file in java, but file performed not completely. Code look like:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c call "+path);
```

When I try to run it manually, without java, batch works correct.

Batch file contains next code:

```
cd C:\Downloads\
if not exist Documents mkdir Documents
move *.odt Documents
move *.doc Documents
if not exist Archives mkdir Archives
move *.tar Archives
move *.gz Archives
if not exist Music mkdir Music
move *.mp3 Music
```

Java complete batch only to fifth line. Has anyone faced this?

---

Hm, with [batch](http://pastebin.com/DqXegSTL), it stoped again [here](http://pastebin.com/RnA8k67U). And Java code: [link](http://pastebin.com/NfkHg8P3). If add to somename.ogg to downloads folder, script goes to next line. All folders (Archives, Documents etc) are already exists, and downloads folder doesn't contain *.zip, *.tar, *.docx, *pdf files, but these lines passed without problems. Why it stoped precisely at ogg-line?

Comment: did you call `waitFor()` on the process returned by `exec(...)`?

Comment: If I use it, process doesn't completed(

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that there is a bug in your batch script.  The [MSDN documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/if.mspx) for the `if` command states this:

> You cannot use the if command to test directly for a directory, but the null (NUL) device does exist in every directory. As a result, you can test for the null device to determine whether a directory exists. The following example tests for the existence of a directory:
>
> `if exist c:\mydir\nul goto process`

Now the way you are using it (`if not exist directory mkdir directory`) is likely to succeed if the directory doesn't exist ... but attempt to create the directory a second time if it does exist.  Ooops ...

---

Now, your Java application read and printed out the contents of the error stream for the process, you'd most likely see an error message telling you that the `Archives` directory already existed.  Ignoring the output is asking for trouble, IMO.

Comment: @panzersoldat - so have you changed you code to read and print the output from the process yet?

Answer (score 0):

I bet `path` in your Java program contains spaces or something similar. Are you quoting that properly?

Btw: Runtime.exec() has been superseeded with ProcessBuilder which can handle arguments much better than Runtime.exec()

Try this:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c",  "call \"" + path "\""); 
builder.start();
```

Comment: There is no problem with spaces, because batch start run, and move *.odt and *.doc to Documents, problem begins from second "if" statement.

Comment: Also your variant doesn't begin at all.

Answer (score 0):

OMG, GUYS!

I don't understand why, but:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "call", "\"" + "sort.bat" + "\""); 
builder.start();
```

doesn't works, BUT:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "call", "\"" + "sort.bat" + "\""); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(builder.start().getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

works correctly! %)

If anybody understands this, please, explain this.

Comment: Looks like either your process simply was not finished when your Java program finished and got killed then, or that the process wanted to output something and couldn't (since you didn't read it), thus waiting on the read to be successful.

Comment: welcome to SO, don't post a new answer to your own question, please edit your question, instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not careful with your stdout and stderr streams it's **very** easy to deadlock ProcessBuilder or Runtime.exec(). The article [`When Runtime.exec() won't`](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) over at JavaWorld contains a lot of useful information on this and a couple of other pitfalls.

If possible, I would suggest using [Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) because all the required stream pumping is done for you.